Ajax Form with 3 successive selects
I am looking to create a form consisting of 3 "select" elements present from the page load, where only the first one has options at this stage.
These selects are populated by a taxonomy of depth 2 (Parent -> child -> child).
The "level_0" element is the first select, initialized with the "Parent" terms.
When a selection is made in the "level_0" element, the second "select" (level_1) displays the direct "children" of the term selected in "level_0", and it works the same way when a selection is made in "level_1".
This form works more or less: the "select" elements are correctly updated via Ajax, but an error occurs when a selection is made on "level_1":
The submitted value [xx] in the Modèle element is not allowed.
Here is a link to a short video that shows the problem: http://partage.acces-piste.com/Drupal-custom-form.webm
I think this is because the select values are not the ones present at the time of form initialization, but I don't see how to fix it.
Here is my Form :
<?php

namespace Drupal\ald_products\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class AldProductsSelectMotosForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'ald_products_custom_select_moto';
  }

  /**
   * @param array $form
   * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
   * @return array
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = [];

    // Requête pour récupérer les termes de niveau 0 de la taxonomie "motos"
    $vid = 'motos';
    $terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, 0, 1);

    $options = ['' => 'Sélectionnez la marque'];
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $options[$term->tid] = $term->name;
    }

    // Sélecteur pour les marques
    $form['level_0'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Marque',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::updateModels',
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'models-wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    // Sélecteur pour les modèles (vide par défaut)
    $form['level_1'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Modèle',
      '#options' => ['' => 'Sélectionnez la marque',],
      '#prefix' => '<div id="models-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::updateYears',
        'event' => 'change',
        'wrapper' => 'years-wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    // Sélecteur pour les années (vide par défaut)
    $form['level_2'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Année',
      '#options' => ['' => 'Sélectionnez le modèle',],
      '#prefix' => '<div id="years-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    // Bouton de soumission
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Valider',
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Callback pour mettre à jour les modèles.
  */
public function updateModels(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
  $selected_brand = $triggering_element['#value'];

  // Ajouter l'option par défaut "Choisissez le modèle"
  $options = ['' => 'Choisissez le modèle'];

  if ($selected_brand) {
    // Requête pour récupérer les modèles en fonction de la marque sélectionnée
    $vid = 'motos';
    $terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $selected_brand, 1);

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $options[$term->tid] = $term->name;
    }
  }

  $form['level_1']['#options'] = $options;
  $form['level_1']['#default_value'] = '';

  return $form['level_1'];
}


  /**
   * Callback pour mettre à jour les années.
   */
  public function updateYears(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();

    $selected_model = $triggering_element['#value'];
    $options = ['' => 'Sélectionnez l\'année'];

    if ($selected_model) {
      // Requête pour récupérer les années en fonction du modèle sélectionné
      $vid = 'motos';
      $terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid, $selected_model, 1);

      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $options[$term->tid] = $term->name;
      }
    }

    $form['level_2']['#options'] = $options;
    $form['level_2']['#default_value'] = '';

    return $form['level_2'];
  }

  /**
   * @param array $form
   * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
    $moto = $form_state->getValue('moto');

    if (ctype_digit($moto['level_0'])) {
      $session->set('moto', $moto);
    } else {
      $session->remove('moto');
    }
  }
  
}

Thank you in advance for your help.

You are not allowed to change $form in an Ajax callback. See this callback from the Examples module:
  /**
   * Provide a new dropdown based on the AJAX call.
   *
   * This callback will occur *after* the form has been rebuilt by buildForm().
   * Since that's the case, the form should contain the right values for
   * instrument_dropdown.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The current state of the form.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The portion of the render structure that will replace the
   *   instrument-dropdown-replace form element.
   */
  public function instrumentDropdownCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['instrument_fieldset_container'];
  }

The changed part of $form is only returned, not built.
The rebuilding takes place in DependentDropdown::buildForm().

Thank you very much, that saved me a lot of time.
Now, I just need to refine the HTML and CSS output, and preserve the values in SESSION to pre-populate in case of returning to the page later.
Have a nice day !
PS : Should I mark this question as 'solved'?
